# Does the use of 'this' keyword within a constructor increase memory usage overall?

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, p5.js

For example:

```js
function Constructor() {
  this.peoperty = 1;
  this.myMethod1 = function() {
    //do something
  };
  this.myMethod2 = function() {
    let a = myMethod3();
  }
  
  /*no 'this' keyword for myFunction3,because 
    I am not going to call myFunction3 anywhere else,
    except inside this particular Constructor*/
  myMethod3 = function() {
    let b = 0;
    return b;
  };
}

var hello = new Constructor();
```

I assume `this` keyword refers to the instance when creating a variable use `new` keyword.

**The question is**, if the `myMethod3` will only be called inside that constructor, can I **not** use `this` keyword for `myMethod3`, because I am not going to use `hello.myMethod3` anywhere in my code. Does this save some memory while running, since I guess only properties/methods that bind with a `this` keyword will occupy memory spaces for each instance created with a `new` keyword?

Comment: if you merely define the function as `function myFunction3()` it's still going to exist in the closure created by `Constructor()`, so you're not saving that much memory. Also, this seems like a premature optimisation.

Comment: No. <rest of the text to fill up comment length requirement>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: What happened when you did some profiling to measure the memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct, if you declare a method in the constructor, every instance will have its own definition:

```js
function Cat() {
  this.meow = function() {
    console.log('meow');
  }
}

const cat1 = new Cat();
const cat2 = new Cat();

cat1.meow();
cat2.meow();

console.log(cat1.meow === cat2.meow);
```

The same doesn't happen if you use the prototype keyword. In that case, both object will have a pointer to the same definition:

```js
    function Cat() {
    }
    
    Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
      console.log('meow');
    }

    const cat1 = new Cat();
    const cat2 = new Cat();
    
    cat1.meow();
    cat2.meow();

    console.log(cat1.__proto__.meow === cat2.__proto__.meow);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your current code, you aren't declaring `myFunction3`, therefore the function will be in the global scope, and every new instantiation of the `Constructor` will override the previous `myFunction3`:

```
 const instance = new Constructor();
 myFunction3 = () => alert("whoops");
 instance.myFunction2(); // "whoops"
```

Therefore there is just one `myFunction3` at a time, which saves memory, however it makes little sense to redeclare it in the constructor then (it never makes sense to not declare variables).

---

Under the assumption that you declared it properly with:

```
 function myFunction3() {
   let b = 0;
   return b;
};
```

then you won't save any memory at all, as a reference to `myFunction3` is kept in the closure of the other functions you assign to `this`, therefore `myFunction3` will have to stay as long in memory as whatever instance `this` is referring to does. If you do

```
 this.myFunction3 = function() { /*...*/ };
```

it will also stay in memory as long as `this` exists, so they are actually equal from a memory point of view. However `myFunction3` is somewhat "private" as it can't be accessed via `this`.